# Trying to push a nuget package to our private feed. Getting ' load failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process'

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, nuget

We have an on premise instance of DevOps Server 2020. I have a dotnet standard 2.0 library that I am  trying to push to our internal nuget feed.

I am getting the error `unable to get local issuer certificate`. I followed the instructions here:[Azure DevOps Server pipeline build fails when using self-signed SSL certificate with "unable to get local issuer certificate" during NuGet restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855546/azure-devops-server-pipeline-build-fails-when-using-self-signed-ssl-certificate)

But now I am getting the error `(node:6056) Warning: Ignoring extra certs from C:\Certs\root.crt, load failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process`

Here is the YAML where I am setting the path to the root cert:

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  NODE.EXTRA.CA.CERTS: 'C:\Certs\root.crt'
```

And here is the YAML where I am packing and pushing the Nuget package:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'off'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: 'b4b089f9-ff2f-4b74-9690-ec6082a4872b'
```

Comment: I did get this working by using the NuGetCommand@2 task. I confess I don't know why it works over the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task. I fought with it all day and made so many changes I don't know which one worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> unable to get local issuer certificate

To resolve this issue, you could try to manually acquire the version of NuGet.exe you wish to use (like [nuget.exe v5.9.1](https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v5.9.1/nuget.exe)) and put it on the private agent in a folder that's on the PATH.

- Download NuGet.exe tool to that agent machine manually(e.g.
  `d:\tool\nuget.exe`).
- Open System Properties window > Advance > Environment variables.
- In System variables section, click New button > Variable name: nuget;
  Variable value: `d:\tool` > Click Ok.
- Select Path variable > Edit > add/append `%nuget%` item (the result
  will be xxxx;`%nuget%`) Restart your machine.

After that you can remove NuGet Tool Installer task from build definition.

If it not work for you, try to running "`.\externals\nuget\nuget.exe update -self`" for the private agent install folder on the agent machine and getting an update version, it works again with the local certificate store:

[image]

You could check [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/builds-failing-after-upgrade-to-azure-devops-serve/437275) for some more details.

Comment: So newer versions of Nuget work with the cert store again? Interesting.