# NuGet Package Artifact not downloading in Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server-2020

I'm currently trying to setup a release pipeline in Azure DevOps server, with multiple Artifacts. The first Artifact is published from a build pipeline and the other artifact is a NuGet Package hosted in an Azure Artifacts feed.

When I create and deploy the release, it successfully downloads the first Artifact without issue, when it moves on to download the NuGet Package, the task is labelled a success, however it fails to download the NuGet package with the below in the logs.

```
2022-02-23T09:53:38.0879772Z ##[debug]SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2022-02-23T09:53:38.0880158Z ##[debug]Got auth token
2022-02-23T09:53:38.0881320Z ##[debug]System.ServerType=OnPremises
2022-02-23T09:53:38.0882074Z ##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
2022-02-23T09:53:38.1247667Z ##[debug]Operation failed, waiting 100ms before retrying, retries remaining: 4
2022-02-23T09:53:42.2527259Z ##[debug]Operation failed, waiting 200ms before retrying, retries remaining: 3
2022-02-23T09:53:46.4835921Z ##[debug]Operation failed, waiting 400ms before retrying, retries remaining: 2
2022-02-23T09:53:50.9173777Z ##[debug]Operation failed, waiting 800ms before retrying, retries remaining: 1
2022-02-23T09:53:55.7558510Z ##[debug]Getting URL from versioning data failed with error: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
2022-02-23T09:53:55.7560354Z ##[debug]Getting download url for this package failed with error: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

[image: Debug Logs]

Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: These might be helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855546/azure-devops-server-pipeline-build-fails-when-using-self-signed-ssl-certificate
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1341

In essence, there might be something amiss with the certificates in the server hosting the pipeline agents or the Node.js executable that the pipeline tasks use can not find the right certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First link from Jukkak in the comments was the answer. Had to export the cert as a .pem file and set an environment variable pointing to it on the agent machine. I tried with the .cer file but that didn't work.