# Unable to download secure files from azure devops

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-pipelines

Good morning,
I have problems checking out a secure file during the build process in azure devops 2019. My task is defined as:

```yaml
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'oimPictureEditor_test'
  displayName: 'download configuration'
```

[image]

but it fails with:

```log
2022-12-30T10:10:27.9053899Z ##[section]Starten: download configuration
2022-12-30T10:10:28.0009766Z ==============================================================================
2022-12-30T10:10:28.0010142Z Task         : Sichere Datei herunterladen
2022-12-30T10:10:28.0010245Z Description  : Hiermit wird eine sichere Datei an einen temporären Speicherort auf dem Agent-Computer heruntergeladen.
2022-12-30T10:10:28.0010357Z Version      : 1.151.2
2022-12-30T10:10:28.0010489Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-12-30T10:10:28.0010653Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file
2022-12-30T10:10:28.0010783Z ==============================================================================
2022-12-30T10:10:28.5506559Z ##[error]Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
2022-12-30T10:10:28.5593478Z ##[section]Abschließen: download configuration
```

does anyone has any idea how to fix this?

thx in advance
iisiggi

Answer (score 0):

Place your secure files on Azure Pipeline and download it.

*Here are the steps:

1. Upload the secure file in Library on Pipeline
2. Download the files in the agent machine with using  `DownloadSecureFile@1`  *task*

[image]

*Download the secure files*

use the download task   `DownloadSecureFIle@1`  task like below.

```
- task: DownloadSEcureFile@1  
  name: <nameof the Task>  
  inputs:  
    secureFile: <secure file Name>
```

*The secure file is downloaded to*  `$(Agent.TempDirectory)`.  *you can check the path with using the prepared variable such as*  `$(<task name>.secureFIlePath)`

*Reference taken from* [MSDoc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thx for the answer. I did exactly what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue for Azure DevOps Server, and you can try the way below to resolve the issue.

```yaml
  steps:
  . . .

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Set CA Cert'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        if ($env:AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY -ne $null) { $TargetFolder = $env:AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY }
        else { $TargetFolder = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('TEMP','Machine') }
        Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\CA | ForEach-Object {
          $Cert = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`n"
          $Cert+= $([System.Convert]::ToBase64String($_.export([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Cert),'InsertLineBreaks'))
          $Cert+= "`n-----END CERTIFICATE-----`n"
          $Chain+= $Cert
        }
        $CertFile = "$TargetFolder\TrustedRootCAs.pem"
        $Chain | Out-File $CertFile -Force -Encoding ASCII
        $Chain = $null
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NODE.EXTRA.CA.CERTS]$CertFile"

  - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    displayName: 'download configuration'
    inputs:
      secureFile: 'oimPictureEditor_test'

  . . .
```

The step '**`Set CA Cert`**' will try to get the CA certificate and set it as the variable "**`NODE.EXTRA.CA.CERTS`**" for use.

For more details about this issue and the solution, you can reference the following tickets:

- [Azure DevOps Server pipeline build fails when using self-signed SSL certificate with "unable to get local issuer certificate" during NuGet restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855546/azure-devops-server-pipeline-build-fails-when-using-self-signed-ssl-certificate)
- https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11508

Comment: This looks great. But do you know how to enforce, that the powershell task runs before DownloadSecureFile@1?

Comment: Hi @iiSiggi, Just like as above sample I shared, adding the PowerShell@2 task to execute script before the DownloadSecureFile@1 task. With this method, every time when you run the pipeline job, it will run the PowerShell@2 task then run the DownloadSecureFile@1 task.

Answer (score 0):

I put the content of my secret file into a secret variable. That worked for me, but is for sure no general solution.

Answer (score 0):

I set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS as system variable manually, than restarted the agent service. That worked for me.