# Unable to use download secure file task in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, certificate

I receive an error when using the download secure file task:
##[error]Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

A normal pipeline that executes a powershell script runs without a problem.

I have tried download secure file with a pdf and certificate and get the same errors

For example:

```
steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: 'Download File'
  inputs:
    secureFile: SelfSigned.pfx
```

```
steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: 'Download File'
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'test.pdf'
```

I have tried the following

1. git config --global http.sslbackend schannel, I have always had this
2. I have tried to copy the all certiicates from the tfs server to ca-bundle.crt using the instructions in the links below, originally I had just the root certificate
3. git config --global http.sslVerify false (reverted after it didn't work)

[SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate AZURE DEVOPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67976050/ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-azure-devops)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/phkelley/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. You can refer the following tickets and run the PowerShell script to solve the issue.

- [Azure DevOps Server pipeline build fails when using self-signed SSL certificate with "unable to get local issuer certificate" during NuGet restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855546/azure-devops-server-pipeline-build-fails-when-using-self-signed-ssl-certificate)
- [unable to get local issuer certificate](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11508)

  ```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Set CA Cert'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        if ($env:AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY -ne $null) { $TargetFolder = $env:AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY }
        else { $TargetFolder = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('TEMP','Machine') }
        Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\CA | ForEach-Object {
          $Cert = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`n"
          $Cert+= $([System.Convert]::ToBase64String($_.export([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Cert),'InsertLineBreaks'))
          $Cert+= "`n-----END CERTIFICATE-----`n"
          $Chain+= $Cert
        }
        $CertFile = "$TargetFolder\TrustedRootCAs.pem"
        $Chain | Out-File $CertFile -Force -Encoding ASCII
        $Chain = $null
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NODE.EXTRA.CA.CERTS]$CertFile"
  ```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, I tried that and the Download secure file gets run first with pre-job in front of the task name. So what worked was that I declared a variable in the pipeline with the path to the TrustedRootCAs.pem path and added a     env:
      NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS: to reference it in the yaml file. Not sure why the download gets done first even though it is second on the steps.